# How to get latest Joomla version from Joomla API into custom component

Tags: joomla-api

Ok, so I've created a custom component that should provide a dashboard to users of the site. A critical piece of information on it, is the latest Joomla version according to Joomla. So if I would check it now I would retrieve version 3.6.5.

Now I've understood that I'm able to retrieve this through the Joomla API. I know shares developers information through a dedicated API but I'm not sure on how to get this piece of data specifically.

Anyone who has experience with this. The Joomla documentation is a little thin on this, or is it just me?

Answer (score 2):

Recently we launched a public API on the Joomla Downloads site for things like this.  Take a look at https://downloads.joomla.org/api-docs/ for information on all of the available endpoints.  Specifically, you'll want to work with the https://downloads.joomla.org/api/v1/latest/cms endpoint.

Also to add, not all of the Joomla releases have tags on the Git repository.  The tags weren't transferred over at all when the code was migrated from the old SVN repository.  For every release since 1.7.3 in late 2011 the data will all be there, but the one canonical source for all of the releases (dates, packages, versions) all the way back to 2005 will be the downloads site since we transferred over all of the non-version controlled resources from the old JoomlaCode site.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use GitHub public releases API → https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release

Every single release of Joomla is here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases so you can easily get info even about alpha/beta versions.